# How to get the retweet count date wise

Tags: twitter

please some tell me that how can i get the twitter's retweet datewise
this is how i am calling the api: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets_of_me.json
in the API Console of twitter. What are the parameters i can add more to the above url to get the data datewise, ex: on 7th oct its count is 10
on 8th is 5, etc.
i can see any parameter for date here: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweets_of_me

Answer (score 1):

The API won't do this for you - you will have to code it yourself.  The date of the retweet is in the "created_at" property.

Comment: thanx for your reply @DWRoelands :)
please see this thread on twitter community
https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-get-the-retweet-count-date-wise/25166/3
please try to help me on the reply i posted below :)

Comment: You will have to gather all of the retweets and then interrogate the "created_at" property of each one to assign them to date ranges.  The API will not do this for you.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion DW :)
i will try to come up with positive solution